# Joint probability distribution of Bernoulli & Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

"Let the random process K(t) depend on uniform Poisson process N(t), with the mean arrival rate λ>0, as follows: Starting at t = 0, both N(t) = 0, and K(t) = 0. When an arrival occurs in N(t), an independent Bernoulli trial takes place with probability of success p, where 0>p>1.

On success, K(t) is incremented by 1, otherwise K(t) is left unchanged. Find the PMF of the discrete valued random process K(t) at time t, that is, P<sub>k</sub> (k ; t),for t ≥ 0."

---

So far, I've assumed the following...

The probability of k arrivals in interval t follows the distribution

**P(k arrivals in time t)=((λt)<sup>k</sup> e<sup>-λt</sup>)/k!**

And PMF of K(t) conditioned on a fixed number of k arrivals from the Poisson process

**P(K(t) = i | K = k) = C<sub>k,i</sub>(p)<sup>i</sup>(1-p)<sup>k-i</sup>**

However, I am stuck trying to get the PMF of K(t) unconditioned on K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
P(K(t) = i)
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(K(t) = i \mid N(t) = n) P(N(t) = n)
\\
&= \sum_{n=i}^\infty \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i} \cdot e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?

> Continuing from above, use $\binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{i! (n-i)!}$ and some rearranging to obtain $$P(K(t)=i) = e^{-p \lambda t} \frac{(p \lambda t)^i}{i!} \cdot \underbrace{e^{-(1-p) \lambda t}\sum_{n=i}^\infty  \frac{((1-p) \lambda t)^{n-i}}{(n-i)!}}_{=1}.$$ Do you recognize this PMF?

Comment: This is great, thanks! I didn't to split out the summation as you've done.

That PMF looks like a specialized version of the Poisson distribution which incorporates the Bernoulli trials, but I don't know what its name is.

Comment: @julez1234 Yes, it is just a Poisson distribution with mean $p\lambda$.

Comment: Nice answer. How come the sum runs from $n=0$ on the first line and $n=i$ on the second line? Should it still be $n=0$ on the second line? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT $P(K(t)=i \mid N(t)=n)$ is the probability of $i$ successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials. This is zero if $n < i$.

Comment: @angryavian, oh yes of course, got it thanks!